# Not able to create in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

my code might be messy but here is what i got at the moment

```
public IActionResult WeeklyInvoiceNumber()
{
    int id = 1;    
    var whtev = _invNumRepo.GetSingle(i => i.id == id);
    InvoiceWeekViewModel vm = new InvoiceWeekViewModel();
    vm.InvoiceNum = whtev.InvoiceNum;
    var help = vm.InvoiceNum;
    int invoice = ++help;
    if (DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
    {
        vm.InvoiceNum++;
    }
    if (vm.InvoiceNum == invoice)
    {
        InvoiceNumber InvNum = whtev;   
        if (ModelState.IsValid && InvNum != null)
        {
            InvNum.InvoiceNum = vm.InvoiceNum;
            _invNumRepo.Update(InvNum);
        }
    }            
    return View(vm);
}
```

Instead of

> _invNumRepo.Update(InvNum);

i can use

> _invNumRepo.Create(InvNum);

which goes to this in the BaseRepository:

```
public void Create(T entity)
{
    _dbSet.Add(entity);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

, but has a problem at the

> _context.SaveChanges();

bit saying

> An exception of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code

Thanks in advance and if you need anymore info just ask.

Comment: add try catch block to your code in Create method of BaseRepostiory. Look for error details on debug

Comment: Why do you want to get an invoice number without an invoice? Just set up the invoice, post it and in the post method save the invoice first. If that was successfully then calculate the next invoice number and set it to the just created invoice.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use

> _context.SaveChangesAsync();

instead of your

> _context.SaveChanges();